# From Word to an Excel sheet using Python

Tags: python, excel, ms-word

So I am trying to convert Word files to Excel files, so that it is in a table format. The problem is, the Word files are not created by using tables.

For example, the format of a file looks like this:

**Type**

*Subject*

Date: 20/05/2021

Source: source1, source 2

1. First item
2. Second item
3. Third item

Is it possible to convert Word documents to Excel (using Python) by using the lay-out of the document? For example, by using that certain parts of text are in bold, or are bullet items? Such that it looks like the following:

Type - subject - date - Source (unknown) - Item 1

Type - subject - date - source (unknown) - item 2

Type - subject - date - source 3 (unknown) - item 3